# Register device with Amazon SNS using appery.io

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, gsm, amazon-sns

I want to create a mobile APP with appery.io so I can easily export the APP for iphones, Android phones and Microsoft phones. 
My problem is that the APP needs to register with Amazon SNS to get notifications through GSM or APNS. I know it is somehow possible to do this with phonegap but I couldn't find any useful example. I have never worked with SNS or GSM/APNS before, so I am completely lost at the moment. 
Have someone ever worked with appery using SNS and/or GSM/APNS? Or have any clues for me?